# Initializing LinkedList with the List interface casts the LinkedList at later use

Tags: java, linked-list

I've got the following bit of code initializing a LinkedList:

```
List<Node> optimal = new LinkedList<>();
```

Now, when I want to use the initialized LinkedList:

```
optimal.addFirst(new Node(i, p));
```

I get an error "Cannot resolve method" inside IntelliJ. Now, if I let IntelliJ autocomplete my code when calling the `addFirst();` I get the following line:

```
((LinkedList<Node>) optimal).addFirst(new Node(i, p));
```

Is there a reason I have to cast the optimal list to LinkedList specifically?

I also tried the following line a bit later which runs fine, without any need to cast:

```
optimal.add(new Node(i, p));
```

From what I remember you don't need any casting when initializing with an interface instead of the implementation, so am I missing something here? Is this perhaps specific to the `addFirst()` method?

Comment: Use the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface rather than the `List` interface if you need a `Deque` rather than a `List`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`addFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addFirst-E-) is provided by the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface.  Defining `optimal` as a `List` does not give you access to that method.  One solution is to define `optimal` as a `Deque` instead:

```
Deque<Node> optimal = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for the explanation. I'll accept the answer, once I can.

Comment: if you are using java 10 then you could do this  `var optimal=new LinkedList<>();`

Answer (score 1):

Either declare it Deque or LinkedList

```
Deque<Node> optimal = new LinkedList<>();
```

Or

```
LinkedList<Node> linkedlist = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are encountering here is called [polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm). `LinkedList<T>` class implements interface `List<T>` thus it will have all the methods provided by [`List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) . Since your first line of code is

```
List<Node> optimal = new LinkedList<>();
```

it says that `optimal` is of type List, thus it will only have access to methods defined in [List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). As you see on the linked page, addFirst is not a method of List, its a method on LinkedList (or Deque interface).

If you want to add something to begining of the list without changing your code, then you can use

```
void add(int index, E element);
```

with index set to 0,

```
optimal.add(0, new Node(i, p));
```

so that element is added as first element of the list.

To get back to your question:

> Is there a reason I have to cast the optimal list to LinkedList specifically?

Yes, you defined optimal to be a List. List does not have such method call addFirst. Your only option is cast optimal to LinkedList or [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (LinkedList class implements the interface Deque)